# Angular unit testing form validation - control stays untouched

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

I've an Angular component which has form validation. I'm unit testing to make sure it displays an error message if the input is invalid.

But when I try to change the `<input>` box value, the control's state remains `untouched` and the error doesn't display.

Here's the code:

```
<form #zipForm="ngForm">
<label>
    <input type="text" id="postalCode" [(ngModel)]="postalCode" #postalCodeElem="ngModel" name="postalCode" [pattern]="validationPattern" required>
    <button type="button" (click)="click(postalCodeElem.value)">Enroll</button>
    <div *ngIf="postalCodeElem.invalid && postalCodeElem.touched">
    <span id="required-postal-code" *ngIf="postalCodeElem?.errors?.required">
        zip/postal code is required
    </span>
    <span id="invalidPostalCode" *ngIf="postalCodeElem?.errors?.pattern">
        zip postal code is invalid
    </span>
    </div>
</label>
</form>
```

Test file:

```
it('should show error in case of invalid postal code', () => {
    const elem: HTMLElement = fixture.nativeElement;
    const inputElem: HTMLInputElement = elem.querySelector('input');

    inputElem.value = 'L5L2';
    inputElem.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));

    fixture.detectChanges();

    const invalidErrorElem: any = elem.querySelector('span');

    console.log('elem', elem);
    console.log('invalidErrorElem', invalidErrorElem);

    expect(invalidErrorElem).not.toBeNull();
});
```

I've created a stackblitz to demo the issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-45zwkn?file=app%2Fapp.component.spec.ts

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to focus and blur your input:

```
inputElem.focus();
fixture.componentInstance.postalCode = 'L5L2';
inputElem.blur();
fixture.detectChanges();
```

Comment: I tried and it doesn't seems to be working either. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-hmhzba?file=app%2Fapp.component.spec.ts

Comment: Oh my bad, I didn't realize you were hiding the error message until it was touched. You need to focus the input and then blur. That's why it's not appearing.

Comment: hey that worked perfectly. Can you please edit your answer and put this there so that I can accept your answer? Thanks for your help!!